gettting dl/dx shape from conv(padded dl/dz, rot180 kernels) in convolution neural networks
I am implementing cnn from scratch and I am stucked in dl/dx during backward propagation
Architecture:
28 x 28 input image
Layer 1

conv layer 1 kernels = 32 x 3 x 3
output shape = 32 x 26 x 26
max pooling size and stride = 2 x 2
output shape = 32 x 13 x 13

Layer 2

conv layer 2 kernels = 64 x 32 x 3 x 3
output shape = 64 x 11 x 11
max pooling size and stride = 2 x 2
output shape = 64 x 5 x 5

Fully connected layers

fully connected layer 1 = 128 neurons
fully connected layer 2 = 100
neurons  output layer = 10

Backpropagation
now I have successfully calculated all the gradients
ignoring fc layers lets jump to the gradients of Convolution layers
flatten layer converted back to pooled outs of layer 2 which is 64 x 5 x 5
Layer 2:

calculated dl/dc dc/dz and then dl/dz which shapes become 64 x 11 x
11
calculate dl/dk with formula conv(x, dl/dz)  x is pooled outs of
layer 1  calculate dl/db with formula sum(dz)

Stucked point is dl/dx
means the gradient of pooled outs of previous layer which is layer 1 and shape is 32 x 13 x 13
formula for dl/dx is conv(padded(dl/dz), rot180(kernels)
but how can I get the shape of 32 x 13 x 13
dl/dz shape is 64 x 11 x 11
kernels shape is 64 x 32 x 3 x 3
